Delete all files in a folder (but not the folder itself) except for specific type files
I have a folder with lots of subfolders, each subfolders contain a .cpp file and multiple unimportant files. I want to run a command that go inside each subfolder and delete everything but the folder itself and the .cpp file.
I've tried this command but it just deleted the folder itself:
gci -Path $path | ? {!($_.Name -ilike "*.cpp")} | % { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }

Thank you in advance!

If a folder doesnt have a .cpp file in it, should it be deleted?

Yes, but I can ensure that all folders have at least a .cpp file. Thank you!

If all folders have at least one .cpp in them, then you should only care about finding all files that don't have a .cpp extension and deleting them so, add -Recurse, -File and -Exclude *.cpp to your Get-ChildItem call:
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Exclude *.cpp | Remove-Item


If you want to only work on the immediate subdirectory, use -Depth 0 instead of -Recurse.
